# values beneath the location co-ordinates provided by google maps

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

[The values below the latitude and longitude displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkZAn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the latitude and longitude expressed in decimal degrees. [Decimal Degrees on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).